# How to bind dynamically created fields to an array on form submission in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a form on a razor view page where I am adding rows dynamically using jQuery. I want to bind the dynamically created fields to an array so that I can browse through the array one at a time and insert them to a table in the database. The problem is the fields appear in the "FormCollection" as individual fields rather than as an array.

Please see the attached image for view page:
[image]

jQuery script to add new rows:

```
$(function() {
    var tableRowNum = 1;
    $("#add-work-row").click(function () {
        tableRowNum++;
        var tableRow = "<tr>";
        tableRow += "<td><input name='works[" + (tableRowNum - 1) + "].workCover' type='checkbox' class='text' /></td>";
        tableRow += "<td><input name='works[" + (tableRowNum - 1) + "].workTitle' type='text' class='text work-title caps' /></td>";
        tableRow += "<td><input name='works[" + (tableRowNum - 1) + "].workComposers' type='text' class='text work-composer caps' /></td>";
        tableRow += "<td><input name='works[" + (tableRowNum - 1) + "].workPerformances' type='text' class='text work-performances' /></td>";
        tableRow += "<td><input name='works[" + (tableRowNum - 1) + "].workDuration' type='text' class='text work-duration input-duration' /></td>";
        tableRow += "<td><a href='#' class='delete-row'></a></td>";
        tableRow += "</tr>";
        $("#worksTable").append(tableRow);
        return false;
    });
});
```

The controller action is:

```
public ActionResult CreateReport(FormCollection form)
{
    // works is null?
    var works = form["works"];           
    foreach (var work in works)
    {
        // Do something                
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Do not use `FormCollection` In MVC you bind to your model. And you have not even shown how your generating the new rows or the model you need to bind to.

Comment: Instead of `FormCollection` use `IEnumerable<YourViewModel>`, where the `YourViewModel` represents a row in a table. See Phil Haack's artile on model binding: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have added the jquery script that is adding rows to the table. I can probably create a model with a property works[] and bind to it. But I read in another SO answer that if we name the fields as "works[0].fieldName" it will bind to an array named "works". The concept didn't work here.

Comment: No, it would bind to a model that contains a property named `Works` which is a collection of a model that contains properties named `WorkCover`, `WorkTitle` etc. but there are other problems with your code and it will never work if you deleted an item.

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for 2 options for how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The script for adding new rows should be as follows.

Notice the `works` prefix in input field names, it will be used in the MVC controller action.

Also, the `worksPerformedCollection` is the same as the name of the property in your viewmodel that contains rows for "Works Performed" section.

The `index` (specifically, `works.worksPerformedCollection.index`) is used to group inputs per row. It is not needed if `tableRowNum` is sequential, but needed if it's not. I am guessing your rows may not be sequentially numbered since you have the functionality in UI to remove rows.

```
$(function() {
    var tableRowNum = 1;
    $("#add-work-row").click(function () {
        tableRowNum++;
        var tableRow = "<tr>";
        // Index value for grouping (non-sequential) rows.
        tableRow += "<td><input type='hidden' name='works.worksPerformedCollection.index' value=" + (tableRowNum - 1) + " /></td>";
        // Checkbox.
        tableRow += "<td><input name='works.worksPerformedCollection[" + (tableRowNum - 1) + "].workCover' type='checkbox' class='text' value='true' />";
        tableRow += "<input type='hidden' name='works.worksPerformedCollection["+ (tableRowNum - 1) +"].workCover' value='false' /></td>";

        tableRow += "<td><input name='works.worksPerformedCollection[" + (tableRowNum - 1) + "].workTitle' type='text' class='text work-title caps' /></td>";
        tableRow += "<td><input name='works.worksPerformedCollection[" + (tableRowNum - 1) + "].workComposers' type='text' class='text work-composer caps' /></td>";
        tableRow += "<td><input name='works.worksPerformedCollection[" + (tableRowNum - 1) + "].performances' type='text' class='text work-performances' /></td>";
        tableRow += "<td><input name='works.worksPerformedCollection[" + (tableRowNum - 1) + "].duration' type='text' class='text work-duration input-duration' /></td>";
        tableRow += "<td><a href='#' class='delete-row'></a></td>";
        tableRow += "</tr>";
        $("#worksTable").append(tableRow);
        return false;
    });
});
```

The input fields in the "Performance Details" section should be named as `works.performanceDate`, `works.performerName`, etc.

On the server side you have the following classes.

```
public class PerformanceViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime PerformanceDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PerformerName { get; set; }

    // ...

    public IEnumerable<WorksPerformedViewModel> WorksPerformedCollection { get; set; }
}

public class WorksPerformedViewModel
{
    public bool WorkCover { get; set; }
    public string WorkTitle { get; set; }
    public string WorkComposers { get; set; }
    public int? Performances { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Duration { get; set; }
}
```

And in the MVC controller you have this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateReport(PerformanceViewModel works)
{
    // ...
}
```

Notice that the controller action accepts the viewmodel as `works` - this is the same prefix used when naming input fields on the client side.